# Python script opens process but not sending mail

Tags: python, email, python-2.7, process

I'm in the making of a script that checks if a program is running and then sending a email to confirm it. So far my script only opens the program but does not email me. I'd like to change into checking process and then email instead of opening the program.

```
import smtplib
import sys
import os
import csv
import subprocess
from subprocess import CalledProcessError, Popen, PIPE

# Set up mail info
FROM = "it@mail.com"
TO = ["mine@mail.com"] # must be a list
SUBJECTERR = "Batchserver runnning"
TEXTERR = "Batch server running" 
SUBJECT = "Batch Server status "
TEXT = "Batch Server running relax"

#Gives response
cmd = '\\\\sesrv414\\Applications\\Software\\BIN\\system.EXE'
p = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, bufsize=0)
if p.returncode != 1:
  raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, cmd)
  server = smtplib.SMTP("email.serv.net",25) # Send the mail
  messageErr = "From:%s \nTo:%s \nSubject:%s \n\n%s\n" %(FROM, ", ".join(TO), 
  SUBJECTERR,   TEXTERR)
  server.sendmail(FROM, TO, messageErr)
  server.quit()
  raise

 sys.stderr.close();
 sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```

Comment: What happened after these code running?

Comment: It only opens the program but not sending the mail. Like I've written in the explanation :) I want to check process not open program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you raise an exception before sending email.

You have to install `psutil` first to check process in windows OS.
If your process's name is not 'system.EXE', you will have to change value of variable `name` in the code.

Try this:

```
import smtplib
import sys
import os
import csv
import subprocess
from subprocess import CalledProcessError, Popen, PIPE
import psutil
import re

# Set up mail info
FROM = "it@mail.com"
TO = ["mine@mail.com"] # must be a list
SUBJECTERR = "Batchserver runnning"
TEXTERR = "Batch server running" 
SUBJECT = "Batch Server status "
TEXT = "Batch Server running relax"

#Gives response

name = "system.EXE"

running = False
for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if re.search(name, repr(process)):
        running = True
        break
if not running:
    cmd = '\\\\sesrv414\\Applications\\Software\\BIN\\system.EXE'
    p = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, bufsize=0)    


server = smtplib.SMTP("email.serv.net",25) # Send the mail
messageErr = "From:%s \nTo:%s \nSubject:%s \n\n%s\n" %(FROM, ", ".join(TO), 
SUBJECTERR,   TEXTERR)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, messageErr)
server.quit()


sys.stderr.close();
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the problem with not sending the mail. Which worked perfectly now. Still opened the program though. Would just like to check if the process is running.

Comment: @SterlinkArcher Which process do you want to check if it's running? system.EXE?

Comment: Yes system.exe, it's important to know if its running ;)